# Datalabels misplaced in 3D Pie Chart

Tags: angular, highcharts

When data `labels.enabled` is set to true, the data labels are displayed incorrectly. I am using enterprise highcharts in an angular 7 application and the data labels need to be inside the chart because the area is small and so cannot have the data labels outside.

Not sure if it's a known bug or something I am missing. The pie chart works fine in non-3D mode.

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'pie',
    options3d: {
      enabled: true,
      alpha: 45,
      beta: 0
    }
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Browser market shares at a specific website, 2014'
  },
  tooltip: {
    pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
  },
  plotOptions: {
    pie: {
      allowPointSelect: true,
      cursor: 'pointer',
      depth: 35,
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        format: '{point.name}',
        distance: -70
      }
    }
  },
  series: [{
    type: 'pie',
    name: 'Browser share',
    data: [
      ['Firefox', 20.0],
      ['IE', 10],
      {
        name: 'Chrome',
        y: 12.8,
        sliced: true,
        selected: true
      },
      ['Safari', 20],
      ['Opera', 10],
      ['Others', 10]
    ]
  }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-3d.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
```

Comment: Sorry I missed the fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/yogesh44/s6z1u0r5/1/

Comment: I noticed you've already reported this issue as a bug on highcharts GitHub. There you should have the answer soon: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/12078

Comment: yeah I now realised that this is a known bug with highcharts